# How to create new table from existing table using DAX query on PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to create a new table using the existing table using the DAX query of PowerBI, Is there any Best options?

My table is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Modeling tab and select a new table option

[image]

You will get the DAX query edit option something below

[image]

**Query:** Write your query to create a new table from an existing table

```
CustomerOccupation = SUMMARIZE('KPIMapReduce?limit=10000&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true','KPIMapReduce?limit=10000&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true'[CustomergetOccupation],'KPIMapReduce?limit=10000&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true'[ClerkCount],'KPIMapReduce?limit=10000&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true'[DriverCount],'KPIMapReduce?limit=10000&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true'[FarmerCount],'KPIMapReduce?limit=10000&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true'[WorkerCount],'KPIMapReduce?limit=10000&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true'[OthersCount])
```

**Result:** Our new table is ready

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.
You can create a calculated table using DAX from Modelling > New Table and write DAX expression like:

```
MonthlySum = SUMMARIZE(SAP_INCURRED,SAP_INCURRED[Posting Date].[Month],SAP_INCURRED[amount])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhqE0.png)

Another option is just duplicate an existing table from Query Editor
Query Editor > Select a table and right click  > Select Duplicate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFCSf.png)